# Inserting RANK as value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, rank, distinct-values

I am super new to sql and don`t know if it is possible but
I want to select the value of the RANK from the following SELECT DISTINCT output and insert it to first column of a table called Country.

And then select the address_country column and insert it into the second column of the table "Country" but I do not know how to do that. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO Country

SELECT country_code from
            (SELECT DISTINCT address_country,
            RANK() over (order by address_country asc) AS country_code      
            FROM CUSTOMER_INFO Where CUSTOMER_INFO.address_country is not NULL),

SELECT address_country from 
            (SELECT DISTINCT address_country,
            RANK() over (order by adr_country asc) AS country_code          
            FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
            Where CUSTOMER_INFO.address_country is not NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to an an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, then use:

```sql
INSERT INTO Country (address_country, country_code)
SELECT address_country, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY adr_country)
FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE CUSTOMER_INFO.address_country IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that computing `RANK` will yield derived data, or data which might change as the original `CUSTOMER_INFO` table also changes.  Therefore, you might want to rethink your approach which led you to wanting to do this insert in the first place.

Comment: Hello Tim, the above sql worked for me! In my case it is ok to use the value of rank as a data input of another table because this is the requirement for me. Thank you so much! :D